# Tiberium Sun v2.03 NOD savegames

Tags: command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun

I have downloaded this portable version of Tiberium Sun patched v2.03. I have completed the GDI campaign successfully without any errors.

The NOD campaign all until the NoD mission "Sheep's cloth" I get an Internal error in a message, just as the mission starts when I click OK the game exits.

Does anyone know why the campaign keeps exiting? Or alternatively, is there a NOD campaign savegame to bypass this specific mission?